# Setting up LDAP Connection - LDAPError Invalid Credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, ldap

I am trying to connect to via LDAP for the first time. I am just trying to simply check if a user can login. After trying to connect I am getting an invalid credentials error 49 and error code 81 server is unavailable. I am passing the right user credentials so this should be validating and I am able to connect via JXplorer. 
In JXplorer I have my host as ldap.my.edu port as 389
User dn as: Uid=myuser,OU=People, DC=ua,DC=edu
then mypass.

I believe I am not properly translating this to LdapConnection and the network credential. This is my first time so any help would be very appreciated.

```
            const string server = "ldap.my.edu:389/OU=People,DC=my,DC=edu";
            const string domain = "ldap.my.edu";
            string password = "mypass";
            string userName = "myuser";

            try
            {
                using (var ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(server))
                {

                    var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
                    ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
                    ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;
                    ldapConnection.Bind(networkCredential);
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have SSL (**LDAPS**) enabled on this server, which looks to be the case, then you'll want to make sure you set :

```
ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = false
```

Or, you can just not set it at all - `LdapConnection` will default to unsecured port 389 (**LDAP**) by default, if this isn't explicitly set.

An example, using the values you provided in your question, would be something like this (note that I'm applying the domain to the `NetworkCredential` and not the `LdapConnection` class itself) :

```
// the username and password to authenticate
const string domain = "OU=People,DC=my,DC=edu";
string password = "mypass";
string userName = "myuser";

// define your connection
LdapConnection ldapConnection = new LdapConnection("ldap.my.edu:389");

try
{
   // authenticate the username and password
   using (ldapConnection)
   {
       // pass in the network creds, and the domain.
       var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);

       // if we're using unsecured port 389, set to false. If using port 636, set this to true.
       ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = false;

       // since this is an internal application, just accept the certificate either way
       ldapConnection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate += delegate { return true; };

       // to force NTLM\Kerberos use AuthType.Negotiate, for non-TLS and unsecured, just use AuthType.Basic
       ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;

       // authenticate the user
       ldapConnection.Bind(networkCredential);
   }
   catch (LdapException ldapException)
   {
       //Authentication failed, exception will dictate why
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I believe you are definitely correct about this. I replaced the line to false, but I am still getting error 49 and error 81. Have any other hunches to what could be causing this error?

Comment: Hmm, thought for sure that would be it. Unfortunately LDAP errors are notoriously vague, so this is just a guess but two things you could try - change the `ldapConnection.AuthType` to `Basic`, and also, do you use a domain qualifier within your organization? Try logging the user in using the {DOMAIN}\{sAMAccountNAme} format. If all else fails, I would wireshark the connection over port 389 to see if you can gather any more details.

Comment: This maybe a really dumb question, but for this to work do I need to set anything up in the config file or is LDAPConnection able to do this with just this block off code? I'm unable to find a detailed walk through all I am going off is code snippets.

Comment: Not a dumb question by any means, but no, you have everything you need there in the `LdapConnection` class - I put a brief example together, give it a shot.

Comment: Thank you for that! I'll take a look at your example and update after tinkering around with your snippet.

Comment: Where should I add OU=People,DC=my,DC=edu. If I do not add that info when I connect through Jxplorer or another ldap gui I am not able to connect.

Comment: I updated the code - you'll want to set that as `domain` up at the top, or directly in the `NetworkCredential` constructor.

Comment: On  ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic after debugging I'm getting ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecurityContext' threw an exception. The server cannot handle directory requests. This error makes me feel like I am not connecting to the directory properly since I can connect via other means. Also, I added ldapConnection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3; because I noticed I can only connect on that version. Thanks for all the help. Hopefully I will be able to get a break on this soon. Let me know if you have any other ideas. Hopefully someone will see this and have had this issue before

Answer (score 0):

Try port 3268 for Global Catalog